# Passing arguments to another program via command line

Tags: java, program-entry-point

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "file.jar");
```

The above code is how I'm starting another program but I want to pass a string parameter to the file.jar (which I'm executing with this statement), I tried googling some answers and couldn't find any. Is there like a `-args "blah blah"` which I can add to the end? If anyone can help me I'd very much appreciate it. (Preferably with an example)

Happy easter.

Comment: You can just add more parameters to the end of your command, space separated. Or use the array version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

Comment: So anything after the file.jar will be sent as a parameter to main in the new program?

Comment: Yes. Read the Javadoc.